# Combine same indexes of array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which as dynamic nested indexes in e.g. I am just using 2 nested indexes.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 41373
            [1] => 41371
            [2] => 41369
            [3] => 41370
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 41378
            [1] => 41377
            [2] => 41376
            [3] => 41375
        )


)
```

Now I want to create a single array like below. This will have 1st index of first array then 1st index of 2nd array, 2nd index of first array then 2nd index of 2nd array, and so on. See below

```
array(

    [0] =>41373
    [1] => 41378
    [2] => 41371
    [3] => 41377
    [4] => 41369
    [5] => 41376
    [6] => 41370
    [7] => 41375
  )
```

Comment: Please check my updated ans of resulting array

Comment: Is it possible that you can multiple arrays inside your input array, or just 2 arrays only ?

Comment: no they are dynamic they can be more than two..@MadhurBhaiya

Comment: Please edit your question to include this point. Otherwise all solutions will be basic, and assume two arrays only

Comment: will all the internal arrays have same length ? eg: 4 in your current example!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$results = [];
$array = [[1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4]];
$count = 1;
$size = count($array)-1;
foreach ($array[0] as $key => $value)
{
    $results[] = $value;
    while($count <=  $size)
    {
        $results[] = $array[$count][$key];
        $count++;
    }
    $count = 1;
}
```

Comment: [as per OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52369608/combine-same-indexes-of-array?noredirect=1#comment91683936_52369608), multiple arrays can exist inside the input array

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
function dd(array $arrays): array
{
    $bufferArray = [];
    foreach($arrays as $array) {
        $bufferArray = array_merge_recursive($bufferArray, $array);
    }

    return $bufferArray;
}
```

Comment: You should explain what your code does (and maybe the expected output).

Answer (score 0):

```
$array1 = ['41373','41371','41369','41370'];
$array2 = ['41378','41377', '41376', '41375'];

$return = array();
$count = count($array1)+count($array2);
for($i=0;$i<($count);$i++){
    if($i%2==1){
        array_push($return, array_shift($array1));
    }
    else {
        array_push($return, array_shift($array2));
    }
}


print_r($return);
```

Answer (score 0):

first count the arrays in the given array, then count the elements in the first array, than loop over that. All arrays should have the same length, or the first one should be the longest.

```
$laArray   = [
        ['41373','41371','41369','41370'],
        ['41378', '41377', '41376', '41375'],
        ['43378', '43377', '43376', '43375'],
    ];

$lnNested   = count($laArray);
$lnElements = count($laArray[0]);
$laResult   = []; 

for($lnOuter = 0;$lnOuter < $lnElements; $lnOuter++) {
    for($lnInner = 0; $lnInner < $lnNested; $lnInner++) {
        if(isset($laArray[$lnInner][$lnOuter])) {
            $laResult[] = $laArray[$lnInner][$lnOuter];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this would be the simplest solution:

```
$firstarr = ['41373','41371','41369','41370'];
$secondarr = ['41378','41377','41376','41375'];
$allcounged = count($firstarr)+count($secondarr);
$dividedintotwo = $allcounged/2;
$i = 0;
while ($i<$dividedintotwo) {
echo $firstarr[$i]."<br>";
echo $secondarr[$i]."<br>";
$i++;
}
```